# How to pass parameters to services from constructor

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass some value from component to service constructor.
my object that trying to pass param.
My code is:

```
 constructor(public af: AngularFire, public userData: UserData ,param: boolean) {
    this.smartTableData = this.af.database.list('events/' + this.userData.user.uid + '/contacts',{
     preserveSnapshot: param, //this param should be taken from component
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'tableNumber'

      }
    });
```

and my component:

```
import {LocalDataSource} from 'ng2-smart-table';

@Component({
  selector: 'basic-tables',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [require('./smartTables.scss')],
  template: require('./smartTables.html')
})
export class SmartTables {
    constructor(protected service: SmartTablesService) {
        this.service.smartTableData.subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.source.load(data);
        });
      }
```

Comment: But I have service that can serve 2 components but the different  only by one conf

Comment: The way it can be handled depends on what `datatopass` is. Generally it can be `setData(datatopass)` method. But the problem is that service is a singleton within an injector it belongs to, and setting `datatopass` in two components simlulateneously will lead to unpredicted results. The question should clarify what essentially happens in `SmartTablesService`.

Comment: I update my post, the value that needed is param its just boolean. one component need it as true and other false. 2 components not the same page.2 components update firebase list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't convenient to do a request in service constructor, because service instance is singleton within current injector. `af.database.list` is called only once on the first injection, and `param` would be injected only once too.

Another problem is that DI happens before component constructor.

It should be

```
constructor(public af: AngularFire, public userData: UserData) {}

getData(param: boolean) {
    return this.af.database.list(...);
}
```